# Command to show branch being tracked and revisions behind by git svn

Tags: git-svn, remote-branch

I just want to know to what I am pushing when I use **git svn dcommit** and from what I am pulling when I **git svn rebase**.

Is there a commandline command I could execute that would give me that information?  I just want the branch name.

Also, is there any way to see how many revisions I'm behind or ahead with git svn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try a dry run: `git svn dcommit --dry-run`, same for rebase.

Comment: I like it.  But I need something that is fast and can show me a number.